# Javascript loop through array quits in the middle

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, return

i have an array i'm trying to loop through by array.length but it stops in the middle of the loop for no reason.

code :

```
    var id = ['88' , '89' , '90' , '91' , '92' , '93' , '94' , '95' , '96' , '97' , '98' ];
    var parent_id = ['1' , '1' , '88' , '1' , '88' , '91' , '93' , '93' , '92' , '90' , '97' ];

    function getAllLearningPaths(id){


    document.getElementById("catdiv").innerHTML += "THIS IS HE CURRENT CATEGORY ID : " + id     + "<br>"; 
    for(var i=0; i < id.length;i++)
    {
    document.getElementById("catdiv").innerHTML += "THIS IS HE CURRENT CATEGORY  PARENT    ID : " + parent_id[i] + "<br>"; 
    if(parent_id[i] == id && id[i] != id)
    {
      document.getElementById("catdiv").innerHTML += "I MADE IT!";
      getAllLearningPaths(parent_id[i]);


    }    
}

for(var i=0; i< Categories.length;i++)
{
    if(Categories[i] == id)
    {
        document.getElementById("l_ids_"+CategoriesValues[i]).checked = true;
       disablerow(document.getElementById("l_ids_"+CategoriesValues[i]), '1');


    }

}           

return;
}
```

categories is populated somewhere else in the code. it's no problem.
the thing is that the first loop dosen't pass the 2nd run.
this code outputs :

THIS IS HE CURRENT CATEGORY ID : 88
THIS IS HE CURRENT CATEGORY PARENT ID : 1
THIS IS HE CURRENT CATEGORY PARENT ID : 1

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks wrong -

```
if(parent_id[i] == id && id[i] != id)
```

`parent_id` looks like an array of ints so the `id` variable would need to be an int to pass this test. You then refer to `i` as an array in the next part of the if statement - `id[i] != id`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it might be this line `if(Categories[i] == id)` you are checking a value in Categories agains the array of id, should you be checking against an index inside of id?

Comment: id is a parameter past to this function

Answer (score 0):

There must be exception thrown. Instead of trying to figure out where the problem is in your code, you should add exception handling (use try catch) and debug it with firebug

Answer (score 0):

```
if(parent_id[i] == id && id[i] != id)
```

In your function, 'id' refers to parent_id because that is the argument that you have passed to the function.

Breaking down this line means:

```
if(parent_id[i] == parent_id && parent_id[i] != parent_id)
```

I would suggest either renaming your argument variable, or the id array.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems to be running twice. I guess you are passing in a string like '88' for id parameter. So it returns 2 for id.length since id is a string.